# How to connect to master in redis from slave

Tags: shell, redis, redis-cli

I have 1 master and 2 slaves. First I'm writining `info replication` to get infromation. If I'm on slave, I try to coonect to master with `redis-cli -h ip-redis-master -a password`. Can I automatize this? For example: `redis-cli -h $(info replication | cut -d ip-addr-master) -a password`. Is it possible?

Comment: what you want is just connect to master automatically?

Comment: @baozilaji because it's my task

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do yet.

Comment: @baozilaji Yes I want to automatically connect to master

Comment: So, you want to get the master's host automatically by the info replication command, and using that to connect the master?

Comment: @baozilaji maybe somehow differently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want this:

```
redis-cli -h `redis-cli info replication|grep master_host|awk -F':' '{print $2}'|awk -F'\r' '{print $1}'` -a master-password
```

Comment: Thanks for help but when I started this command I have error: `Could not connect to Redis at -p:6379: Name or service not known`.

Comment: thanks for hel anyway but it won't work, mb I found other ways

Comment: what's the error info? is the port default value 6379?

Comment: Yes, `Could not connect to Redis at -a:6379: Name or service not known`

Comment: maybe you need to handle this problem step by step:
1、make sure that you can get the master ip info by this command 
```
redis-cli info replication | grep master_host
```
2、remeber the host info and try to connect to master manually
```
redis-cli -h ip -a pass
```
3、if everything is ok, then maybe you need to check is there any invisible character in the result of redis-cli info replication, run this:
```
$(redis-cli info replication|grep master_host|awk -F':' '{print $2}')
```